# Prove that, if all maximal subgroups of a finite group are abelian, at least one of maximal subgroups is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Prove that if all maximal subgroups of a finite group are abelian, at least one of maximal subgroups is normal

Help me some hints

Comment: Use induction on $|G|$. If $N$ is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ then you get the result by applying induction to $G/N$. Otherwise $G$ is simple and the result follows from your previous question.

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: I don't assume that $G$ is simple

Comment: You asked for hints, not a detailed solution! I know you are not assuming that $G$ is simple. But if $G$ is not simple, then it has a normal subgroup $N$ with $|G/N|<|G|$, so you can apply induction to $G/N$ and assume that the result that you are trying to prove is true in $G/N$. It is not difficult to deduce from that that the result is true in $G$, so you are done! What do you not udnerstand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a group all proper subgroups are abelian, so it is a Miller-Moreno group, and therefore solvable.

Comment: What is a Miller-Moreno group?

Comment: It is just a group, all proper subgroups oh which are abelian.  http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1903-004-04/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9.pdf

Comment: Is this true for infinite groups, as well?

Comment: Miller and Moreno are clearly assuming finiteness (although they don't say so). Note also that it's trivially false in a group with no maximal subgroups, so you would need some assumptions on their existence.

Comment: @Derek Holt: OP asks about finite groups.

Comment: @Boris Novikov: I know, but Igor Rivin asked about infinite groups, and I was addressing his query.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Yes, I have understood already. :-)